# Angular 2 component doesn't work with my javascript

Tags: jquery, angular

I noticed that if I write datepicker in the index.html file then jquery knows how to handle it but if the same element is part of angular component then clicking on it will not open the colander meaning jquery doesn’t know this element.
How can I make it recognize the element inside the component template?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? To help us help you, please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

At the top of your component ts file, you could try declaring jquery vars.

```
declare var $ = window.$;
declare var jQuery = window.jQuery;
```